# is there any way to set char-counter maxlength dynamically for paper-input

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.0

I want to set different maxlength for different data, i tried by writing a method in maxlength but it didn't worked, so is there any other possibility

```
<paper-input label="{{data.name}}" id="input" char-counter maxlength="getMaxLength()"></paper-input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a property and set max length to property:

```
   <paper-input label="{{data.name}}" id="input" char-counter maxlength="[[maxValue]]"></paper-input>
```

use a method and return value from method:

```
   <paper-input label="{{data.name}}" id="input" char-counter maxlength="[[getMaxLength()]]"></paper-input>
```

Comment: i would to add one note. If you will use the second method, your maxlenght will not be dynamic. Because function `getMaxLength` will be called only once when the `paper-input` is rendered. So first case is much more better since you can change property `maxValue` anywhere and it will be instatly applied to `paper-input`

Comment: You could use a local property in the second example, like `[[getMaxLength(maxValue)]]`, so the binding's value will be updated on change of that property, according to some more complex logic.